# how does the bootloader pass the kernel command line to the kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot

We can see the kernel command line like this :

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/$ cat /proc/cmdline  
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-122-generic root=UUID=99c66a0a-39c1-451c-9f72-ad1576aafb41 ro quiet splash
```

This command line seems to be what grub has passed to the kernel for booting. How is this command line actually passed to the kernel program? I guess maybe the command line is loaded in memory as a string and a register of the processor (like x1, if arm64 processor) is set to that string address? I'm interested in arm64 case especially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same question sometimes popped up to me. So this is a moment to deep dive.

While **x86** uses [special protocol for booting **Linux**](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.10/x86/boot.html), in the case of **arm64** [a different scheme is used](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.10/arm64/booting.html). For communication with kernel, boot loader puts only single address - loaded *flatten device tree* (**FDT**) into the `x0` register.

Here is excerpt from [Linux and the Device Tree, Runtime configuration](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.10/devicetree/usage-model.html#runtime-configuration):

> In most cases, a DT will be the sole method of communicating data from
> firmware to the kernel, so also gets used to pass in runtime and
> configuration data like the kernel parameters string and the location
> of an initrd image.
>
> Most of this data is contained in the /chosen node, and when booting
> Linux it will look something like this:
>
> ```
> chosen {
>         bootargs = "console=ttyS0,115200 loglevel=8";
>         initrd-start = <0xc8000000>;
>         initrd-end = <0xc8200000>;
> };
> ```

[Here is another example of DT](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/booting-without-of.rst?h=v5.9.8#n613).

Next, during kernel early boot, the **OF/FDT** module parses the passed *device tree* and [fill in `boot_command_line` variable](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/of/fdt.c?h=v5.10#n1055).

Answer (score 3):

1. U-Boot enviroment variable *bootargs* is used to pass kernel
   arguments to kernel via command line. So you have to define this
   enviroment variable in U-Boot manually or with U-Boot script.

   ```
   setenv bootargs <your argumets>
   ```

This is how command line arguments looks in dmesg:

```
Kernel command line: console=ttyS0,115200n8 init=/sbin/init root=/dev/ram rw earlyprintk uio_pdrv_genirq.of_id=generic-uio xenon-mtd-concat.total_flash_size=0x8000000
```

Or you can check command line arguments with

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

2. If you dont want to use U-Boot *bootargs* variable, you can define
   kernel command line string in **menuconfig** CONFIG_CMDLINE, and
   enable the CONFIG_CMDLINE_FORCE to override U-Boot.

`CONFIG_CMDLINE_FORCE=y`

`CONFIG_CMDLINE="console=ttyS0,115200n8 init=/sbin/init root=/dev/ram rw earlyprintk uio_pdrv_genirq.of_id=generic-uio"`

3. Third method is to pass it via compiled device-tree blob. But U-Boot
   has precedence over device-tree. So to use device-tree you should
   delete *bootargs*

`env delete bootargs`

Device tree node example:

```
chosen {
    bootargs = "console=ttyS0,115200 loglevel=8 init=/sbin/init";
```

Answer (score 1):

In the kernel source code **init/main.c**, the kernel entry point is *start_kernel()*:

```c
[...]
/* Untouched command line saved by arch-specific code. */
char __initdata boot_command_line[COMMAND_LINE_SIZE];
[...]
asmlinkage __visible void __init start_kernel(void)
{
    char *command_line;
    char *after_dashes;

    set_task_stack_end_magic(&init_task);
    smp_setup_processor_id();
    debug_objects_early_init();

    cgroup_init_early();

    local_irq_disable();
    early_boot_irqs_disabled = true;

    /*
     * Interrupts are still disabled. Do necessary setups, then
     * enable them.
     */
    boot_cpu_init();
    page_address_init();
    pr_notice("%s", linux_banner);
    early_security_init();
    setup_arch(&command_line);
[...]
    pr_notice("Kernel command line: %s\n", boot_command_line);
[...]
```

In the preceding lines, there is a call to *setup_arch()* to get the command line in an architecture dependent way.

For ARM64, *setup_arch()* is defined in **arch/arm64/kernel/setup.c**:

```
void __init setup_arch(char **cmdline_p)
{
    init_mm.start_code = (unsigned long) _text;
    init_mm.end_code   = (unsigned long) _etext;
    init_mm.end_data   = (unsigned long) _edata;
    init_mm.brk    = (unsigned long) _end;

    *cmdline_p = boot_command_line;
[...]
```

Concerning grub, it is detailed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/547501/435859).

Answer (score 1):

The details vary based on the bootloader and he `head.S` assembly language startup module of the specific kernel.

On Arm64, that startup code is in the file `arch/arm64/kernel/head.S`.

When the startup code is invoked, it assumes that the registers `x0` through `x3` are boot parameters and saves them in the `boot_params` array. Later, C code validates that only the first parameter is nonzero. The other three must be zero; evidently, they were historically used.

Thus, there is only one parameter, effectively. What is it? The `x0` register points to the FDT (flattened device tree).  This device tree blob contains the command line also.

See the code in `drivers/of/fdt.c` how the command line is retrieved from he DT blob (by looking for a node called `"bootargs"`), and retained.

Comment: Thanks, that helps to me. Where to look at.